# Animate an HTML element after a 3D element with gsap

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js, gsap

Im currently developing a website using react.
There is a 3D gtfl model which I successfully managed to animate when the user scrolls using gsap and after the animation of the object is done, I would like to animate a text element.

The text element is supposed to fade away (--> opacity: 0), once the object animation is done.
The code works, but unfortunately, when I am at the very top of the page, the html element starts out as opacity: 0 and after the tiniest bit of scrolling it snaps to it's correct state so it becomes visible and after scrolling further successfully plays it's animation.

Why does it start in the wrong state?

Code:

```
const tl = useRef();
const scroll = useScroll();

const drawer_one = useRef();

useFrame(() => {
    tl.current.seek(scroll.offset * tl.current.duration());
});

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    tl.current = gsap.timeline();
    tl.current
      .to(
        drawer_one.current.position,
        {
          duration: 0.3,
          y: -0.5,
        },
        0
      )
      .fromTo(
        "#direct_work_link",
        {
          opacity: 1,
        },
        {
          opacity: 0,
        }
      );
});`
```

Best regards,
Philip

I already tried using the ScrollTrigger plugin from gsap, as well as the ScrollMagic plugin but to no avail unfortunately.